# Illegal Reflective access operation occurred while I am using hadoop in windows

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, mkdir

Q: When I trying to create a directory using this command "hadoop fs -mkdir /input_dir" in cmd.exe after successful Hadoop installation. I am gettin this error. I will attach the screenshot, below.

> C:\hadoop-2.10.0\sbin>hdfs dfs -mkdir /sample
>   WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
>    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.
>      util.KerberosUtil (file:/C:/hadoop-2.10.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.
>      10.0.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
>    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.
>      security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
>
> > WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> >     WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release mkdir: Call From LGNNV1CC to localhost:9870 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information"

Answer (score 0):

## What does the warning mean?

The program accessed a field/method from another module that was not visible/accessable to it but it made the field/method accessible.

## What is the impact?

In fact, it is just a warning. You can just ignore it.